# Identical hard drives with different sizes (formatting)

Tags: ntfs, formatting, ext4, filesystems

I have two hard drives, which are identical, same model though purchased at different times, but in all respects the same. Afaik the manufacturer hasn't changed capacity (Seagate expansion).

However, they're different sizes. One is NTFS, one is one is ext4. Is this a result of the file system or did they actually change the drive specs?

```
/dev/sdc1             1.8T
/dev/sdd1             1.9T

/dev/sdc1            1922858352
/dev/sdd1            1953512000
```

With regards to filesystem, is there anything which squeezes more space out?

**EDIT**

The NTFS is the larger one, these files come from df.

**Edit 2**
Maybe this should be moved somewhere else.
df is giving a *different* size than fdisk does. Fdisk says they're the same, df says they're different.

Comment: out of curosity, which is which?

Comment: Where are you getting these sizes from?  fdisk? df? parted?

Comment: The "formats" (NTFS, ext4) are called _file systems_.

Comment: df; ntfs is the 'larger'; yeah yeah. Filesystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXT filesystem reserves blocks for privileged processes if you want to remove this reserved space use `sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdc1` you can view the reserved amount by running `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdc1 | grep ‘Reserved block count’`